# Display a new page for each driver in the main report when using multi-value parameter and subr

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am working on a report that uses multiple sub-reports. I have two parameters: t_driver_pk and BatchID for the report. I have been able to display the data for each driver on a new page in the subreport using page break and repeat header options (all the subreports have been grouped by t_driver_pk). But, then when I go to main report and run it selecting multiple drivers on **t_driver_pk** parameter. I am getting a single report that combines the data for all those driver. Essentially, I would like to have it displayed as following:

**Parameters:**
****t_driver_pk****: 5000,4500 **BatchID**:610

**FirstDriver**

Subreport1

Subreport2

Subreport3

Subreport4

**Second Driver**

Subreport1

Subreport2

Subreport3

Subreport4

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your problem exactly? And what have you tried to fix the problem? It may be just me, but I'm having a hard time understanding the question. Some additional formatting on the text, example "code", and added details on the report structure(s) may help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am having problem trying to display the results for each driver that I select in the parameter to display on a different page in the main report. In other words, I would like to have Driver A and the subreports and then the next page begins with Driver B and the subreports.  My aim is to build a main report where users can select multiple drivers and get report for each driver.I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Note that you can (and are even encouraged to) edit your question to add details and clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a Dataset to the report that is driven by the selected t_driver_pk values (i.e. if 5000 and 4500 are selected in the parameter then the new dataset returns the same values).

You should be able to use this dataset with a List data region, which you can insert your subreports into and then pass the current value of t_driver_pk from the new dataset to the subreports. That should repeat them for each value of t_driver_pk.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your answer. I tried adding a new dataset driven by the selected parameter values and added the subreports in the list data region, but it didn't seem to work. I am suspicious if the structure of my report is not built well.

Comment: Actually, we figured it out. All I had to do was to add Distinct in my query. And, just like you said add the subreports in the list data region and it worked like a charm! Thanks Nathan.